# every other character of string in other color

Tags: javascript

I have two variables (both strings) and I need to change color of every other character to green.

```
var a = "big jump";
var b = "bigger jump";
var combined = a.concat(b);
```

I'm not asking for complete code, but a hint, or example.

Comment: You could make an array from string and iterate through this new array changing color of every character.

Comment: at first you can't use numbers for variable names, try to use a and b instead

Comment: Here is your hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @xaxes You can already loop a string like this for(var i = 0; i < str.lenght-1; i++)

Comment: You may want to look at [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com).

Comment: I know that I cant use numbers I just put it there for example...

Comment: @Pointy, I feel like a library is a bit over this guy's head considering the question. Neat library, just maybe not the best timing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give color to every other character, you need to put them in an element that you can style.

Example:

```
var s = "This is a test";

var t = "";
var green = true;
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    var c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c == " ") {
        t += c;
    } else if (green) {
        t += "<span>" + c + "</span>";
        green = !green;
    } else {
        t+= c;
        green = !green;
    }
}
document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = t;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="view"></div>
```

CSS:

```
span { color: green; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Csz62/

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= combined.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 1){
    //add letter with color to something
  } else {
    //add letter with other color to something
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't create a variable that starts with a number (or that is only a number).

You are in javascript, strings don't have colors, you have to change the html (or what you are using) to color the strings

And I don't understand what you want to make, what parts of the string would you want to color ?

Comment: whole string is big jump bigger jump, so every other letter should be green